# Missing files when running ASP.NET Core application in Docker: How to display files when the container is running?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a simple ASP.NET Core solution that I dockerize and seems that some files that are supposedly copied to the output as always are not present when my application is running via Docker.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
ENV RUNNING_IN_DOCKER=true
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS source
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SecretProject.Core/SecretProject.Core.csproj", "SecretProject.Core/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.DAL/SecretProject.DAL.csproj", "SecretProject.DAL/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.Utils/SecretProject.Utils.csproj", "SecretProject.Utils/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.Externals/SecretProject.Externals.csproj", "SecretProject.Externals/"]
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "/"]

RUN dotnet restore "SecretProject.Core/SecretProject.Core.csproj"

FROM source AS build
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SecretProject.Core"
RUN dotnet build "SecretProject.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SecretProject.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SecretProject.Core.dll"]
```

Missing files are the ones there: `SecretProject.Core/Views/EmailTemplates/*.*`

I would like to see the files when the container is running, I am indeed suspecting that not everything is copied.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having all these lines

```
COPY ["SecretProject.Core/SecretProject.Core.csproj", "SecretProject.Core/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.DAL/SecretProject.DAL.csproj", "SecretProject.DAL/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.Utils/SecretProject.Utils.csproj", "SecretProject.Utils/"]
COPY ["SecretProject.Externals/SecretProject.Externals.csproj", "SecretProject.Externals/"]
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "/"]
```

Replace for

```
COPY . .
```